# Java - Is it possible to override an ActionListener in the SuperClass?

Tags: java, action, listeners

If have two classes, `Class A` and `Class B`, B is a subclass of A...if my Class A(the superclass) has a `JButton` with an `ActionListener` which is implemented by an anonymous inner class, how can I override what the button does in the subclass?

Comment: You can't actually override the parents inner class. I'm not sure if such a functionality exists in swing, is it possible to stop the propagation of the event once you have processed it? If so you can add another listener in your subclass that does the processing and does not allow the event to propagate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, you could have the listener call a protected method of some sort:

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            doStuff();
        }
    });
```

Then you can override `doStuff` in the subclass. This seems simpler than mucking about with the events more than you have to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how your code looks like, but here is a rather generic "solution" (not tested):

```
for (ActionListener al : super.getThatButton().getActionListeners())
{
    super.getThatButton().removeActionListener(al);
}
```

And add a new ActionListener afterwards. I *think* that's what you might be looking for, but I'm not sure. I'd just add another ActionListener or make it use Actions instead of ActionListeners.

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to remove the current `ActionListener` and add a new one. You can't extend an anonymous inner class by definition: it's anonymous.

Comment: like the nice chap mentioned above?